# Display the html with special character code intead of just using it as html

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I am using the following line in one of my erb files :

```
<%=@map.div(:width => 800, :height => 500)%>
```

it output the following HTML :

```
&lt;div id="map" style="width:800px;height:500px" &gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

Displayed as : `<div id="map" style="width:800px;height:500px" ></div>`

in the browser.

EDIT : My only other piece of code is :

```
    require 'rubygems'
include GeoKit::Geocoders

class HomeController < ApplicationController

 def index
  coordinates =[13.0343841,  80.2502535] #you can get the coordinates for the location you want from http://stevemorse.org/jcal/latlon.php
  @map = GMap.new('map')
  @map.control_init(:large_map => true, :map_type => true)
  @map.center_zoom_init(coordinates,10) # here 10 referes to the zoom level for a map
  @map.overlay_init(GMarker.new(coordinates,:title => 'Chennai', :info_window => 'Chennai'))
end
end
```

Why is it doing it? How can I prevent rails 3 to translate my code in special char?

Comment: Try putting / at the beginning

Comment: i tried /<%=, </%=,<%/= and <%=/ but it does not works. I am following, that tutorial : https://selvaonrails.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/google-maps-in-rails/#comment-69

Comment: `div` method is inside one of your helpers. show it (application_helper, or home_helper)

Comment: My application helper is empty. I took all the code from here : https://selvaonrails.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/google-maps-in-rails/

Comment: @map come from Gmap that may be part of the gem YM4R : http://ym4r.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

As far as we didn't know anything about `div` method you can try this

```
<%= @map.div(:width => 800, :height => 500).html_safe %>
```

Better to add `html_safe` to output in `div` method